# Javascript pair product

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this problem on Talentbuddy, but I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track. I was wondering if someone could point me i the right direction?

> Pair product
>
> Write to the standard output the greatest product of 2 numbers to be
>   divisible by 3 from a given array of pozitive integers.
>
> Example input: 6, 8, 8, 7, 2, 5
>
> Example output: 48

```
function max_prod(v) {
// Write your code here
// To print results to the standard output please use console.log()
// Example: console.log("Hello world!");
var a = 0
var b = 0
var array = []

for(var x=0;x<v.length;x++)
{
    array[x].append(v)
    if array[x]>a
    {
        a = array[x]
    }
    else if (array[x]<a && array[x] > b)
    {
        b=array[x]
    }
 console.log(a*b)
```

}

edit- I should have included that this is the error message I am getting:

/eval/user_file.js:12 if array[x]>a
                         ^^^^^ 
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: 1) Let x be the largest number divisible by 3. 2) Let y be the largest number not equal to x. The answer is x*y.

Comment: @Matt: I even would've omitted "*not equal to x*" - the assignment doesn't say "different numbers" :-)

Comment: Is there any problem with your code? Why do you think you are not on the right track?

Comment: @Bergi You're correct it doesn't specifically say that, but I doubt that if the list was "1,2,3" that the answer would be 9. Makes more sense to me that it would be 6.

Comment: What did you expect `array[x].append(v)` to do? It definitely does not work - there's no `append` method in JS, and `array[x]` is `undefined`

Comment: @Matt: Still, "*not equal to x*" is not quite correct - it's more complicated than that as the arrays might contain duplicates like in the example. You would expect to get `9` from `1,2,3,3`…

Comment: @Bergi Excellent point - x should then have a different *index* than y.

Comment: @Bergi yes, this is where the error is occurring. I should have included that in the post :/, this is the error message I'm getting:

/eval/user_file.js:12
        if array[x]>a
           ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I suppose if I misremembered append being in Javascript, maybe I need to look up again how arrays work in Javascript.

Comment: @Carm: Did you want `array.push(something)` or `array[x] = something`?

Comment: You get that particular error message because you missed `(...)` around your condition: `if (....)`. The problem with `.append` is a run time error, not a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how your algorithm is going to work. Perhaps you will get couple of ideas from mine:

```
function max_prod(numbers) {

    numbers = numbers.sort(function(a, b) {return b - a;});

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            product = numbers[i] * numbers[j];
            if (product % 3 == 0) return product;        
        }
    }

    return null;
}


max_prod([6, 8, 8, 7, 2, 5]); // => 48
```

You can easily test it in console.